# Hibernate MappedSuperclass via JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private long version;
}
```

and two subclasses:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    private String username;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean isAdmin;

    // constructor/getters/setters etc.
}

@Entity
public class Product extends BaseEntity {
    public String name;
    public BigDecimal price;

    // constructor/getters/setters etc.
}
```

I can query for all subclasses using code:

```
   entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)
                    .createCriteria(BaseEntity.class)
                    .list()
                    .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

how I can get the same results via JPA (without `unwrap`, is it possible?). I tried using `createQuery("from BaseEntity")` but get `BaseEntity not mapped` exception.

EDIT: I know that this will result in two SELECT statement. And it must be MappedSuperclass - I would like to not change that.

Comment: not sure how to create both statements with one query, but you can simply create statements: `createQuery("from User")` and `createQuery("from Product")`.

Comment: @tak3shi I want to grab *all mapped classes* inheriting from BaseEntity without hard coding their names

Comment: you mean _all objects of all mapped classes_ presumably? Some JPA providers allow you to query a MappedSuperclass query class direct, yours doesn't seem to have this capability. No reason why that would be multiple queries FWIW.